# WPF DataGrid refresh cell when calculated column changes

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, observablecollection

Trying to make an interactive grid that updates calculated columns as the user types in values.  Ideally as rows are added and existing rows are changed, the calculated read only cells would update automatically minimally as the cursor leaves the modified cell.  Ideally while the user is typing if performance degradation is not an issue.

With an Entity Data Model such as this:

```
public class CalculatorContext : DbContext
{
    public CalculatorContext() : base("name=CalculatorContext") { }

    public virtual DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Calculation> Calculations { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity()
    {
        Calculations = new ObservableCollection<Calculation>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Calculation> Calculations { get; set; }
}

public class Calculation
{
    [Key]
    public int CalcId { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    public int VariableX { get; set; }
    public int VariableY { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Sum { get { return VariableX + VariableY; } }
    [NotMapped]
    public int Product { get { return VariableX * VariableY; } }

    public virtual MyEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }
}
```

The following grid only refreshes the Sum and Product columns when sorted by that column (or saved and refreshed):

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="calculationsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              Margin="30,30,30,70" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" CellEditEnding="calculationsDataGrid_CellEditEnding" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="variableXColumn" Binding="{Binding VariableX}" Header="X" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="variableYColumn" Binding="{Binding VariableY}" Header="Y" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sumColumn" Binding="{Binding Sum}" Header="Sum" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="productColumn" Binding="{Binding Product}" Header="Product" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Calling DataGrid.Items.Refresh() from the CellEditEnding event simply results in an "InvalidOperationException: 'Refresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction."  I've tried adding some logic to the RowEditEnding, SourceUpdated and SelectedCellsChanged events but am not sure what method to call in order to refresh the screen using the new calculation (add or multiply the variables).  Really only the 2 read only cells on the same row need to be refreshed.

As you can see I am using an ObservableCollection.  Do I need to implment INotifiedChanges or something similar?  If so how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to notify databound controls of property changes dynamically you will want to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged on the elements within your collection. Then on the properties that make up your computed property changes you can also notify that the computed property has changed.

Comment: I have implemented PropertyChanged and the call to Refresh still produces the same InvalidOperationException: 'Refresh' is not allowed.  The main part of my question is what to do with the grid once the event is triggered.  Something like calculationsDataGrid.Items.SourceCollection[e.PropertyName].Refresh(); would be great, but that doesn't work.  Ideally it should only refresh the cells that are calculated on the same row as the property that triggers the change event.

Comment: The thing is, a properly implemented Inotifypropertychanged means you don't need to call refresh. The object changes should automatically bubble to the ui based on the databinding

Comment: So is this not properly implemented?

    public class Calculation : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private int _variableX;
    public int VariableX
    {
        get { return _variableX; }
        set
        {
            _variableX = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VariableX");
       }}

Comment: @DougDekker Almost... You also need to notify that setting `VariableX`results in changes to the affected calculated properties. So your setter should be: `set { _variableX = value; OnPropertyChanged("VariableX"); OnPropertyChanged("Sum"); OnPropertyChanged("Product"); }`. Take note however, that this still falls a little short of your requirement. The calculated values will by default only be updated when you leave the row.